# Setting post meta data to random value during post status transition / on publish

Tags: posts, post-meta, post-status

Upon publishing an unpublished draft, I'd like the custom meta value "post views count" to be set to a random variable between `829` and `1013`.

I am using the code below, which doesn't always work. It works when I **create a test draft and publish it immediately**, but *not* when I save a post for a few days or assign it to another writer it doesn't work.

> NOTE: I don't want to create a new custom field. I just want to update the existing field, which is called `post_views_count`.

```
function wpse_custom_field_on_publish( $new, $old, $post ) {
  if ( $new == 'publish' && $old != 'publish' && !get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', rand(829, 1013), true );
  }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_custom_field_on_publish', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: What do you mean in "it doesn't always work", please be more specific. sidenote, you probably don't use update_post_meta correctly, not sure if it is related.

Comment: I mean if I create a post right now and publish it immediately, the code works, and the views get a random number per the above.

If I create a post and save as a draft, assign it to a different user/editor, then save for review, then publish, it gets published with a view count of 0. That's what I meant by "it doesn't work."

I don't want any posts to be published with a view count of 0. Should I use add_post_meta, or where do you think the issue is?

I am also open to entirely new code.

Comment: @location Additional info always as an [edit], please.

Answer (score 2):

Slight change in your code,

```
function wpse_custom_field_on_publish( $new, $old, $post ) {
    // Only run on "from X > to publish"-transitions
    if ( $new === 'publish' && $old !== 'publish') { 
        $page_views = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true );
        // Only set 'post_views_count' post meta value if there is none so far
        if ( empty( $page_views ) )
             update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', rand( 829, 1013 ) ); 
    }
} 
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_custom_field_on_publish', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Just updated the code with yours, published a post that was saved pending review, but it didn't work. It published with a view count of 0. the post was never published previously.

Comment: Other code is affecting on your page counts, because I checked above code at my end, and it is working fine.

Comment: I tested too, and it does work, except in the drafts I have saved already. Such a frustrating problem.

One last question: How would I go about making the Views field in admin editable? Thank you.

Comment: @location How could a code that runs on the `transition_post_status` hook, which runs _during changes of the status of a post_, affect anything that has no change? I added comments to the code so you better understand the logic behind it.

Comment: @WisdmLabs You might want to consider [`FALSE` return values](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/meta.php#L441-L448) when there is no post ID present and [make sure](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/meta.php#L466-L472) that the code really runs.

Comment: kaiser, thank you for the various contributions to this thread. What can I try to make the code work? The views are always 0, as you'd expect before publishing a post. The posts are normally in pending review, and the date is normally 2 days prior. So I change the date to today, and then publish.