# Updating post_views_count on publish

Tags: views

Upon publishing a post, I'd like the post views count to be a random integer between 829 and 1013.

Could you please tell me what code I need to add to functions.php in order to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: and this [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168342/setting-post-meta-data-to-random-value-during-post-status-transition-on-publis)

Comment: I tried the code provided in those questions, it works SOME of the time, other times it does not. I wanted to ask the question and get a fresh approach from someone.

The answer to this seems to elude the best wordpressers.

I posted followup questions in those threads but didn't get an answer. You should ask questions before downvoting threads next time.

Comment: Actually the code I posted is working but you tried to modify the actual functionality without understanding the code, that must be the issue. I am adding it here and explaining it a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the code I earlier posted.

```
// Create custom field on post publish
function wpse_custom_field_on_publish( $new, $old, $post ) {

  if ( $new == 'publish' && $old != 'publish' && !get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ) ) {
    add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views', rand(829, 1013), true );
  }

}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_custom_field_on_publish', 10, 3 );
```

Let me explain what this code actually does. When you publish or schedule a post, upon publishing this function checks for a custom field named `post_views_count` in your post. If it does not exist then it will create a `post_views_count` custom field and add a random value between 829 and 1013.

I think you had some issue with this code failing some times, so you changed `add_post_meta` with `update_post_meta` which will also fail sometimes because if a post does not already have `post_views_count` meta field then it will skip and do noting.

So what you needed to do instead is to add different tasks for each cases, what to do if this field already exists, else what should it do if it does not.

```
// Create custom field on post publish
function wpse_custom_field_on_publish( $new, $old, $post ) {

  if ( ( $new == 'publish' || $new == 'pending' ) && $old != 'publish' ) {

      if ( !get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ) ) {
          add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', rand(829, 1013), true );
      } else {
          update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', rand(829, 1013) );
      }

  }

}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_custom_field_on_publish', 10, 3 );
```

The idea is still same here. But we added additional task for existing fields.

Now there is some limitation with action `transition_post_status` that it only checks for changes in post status. If you keep changing post status every day/week/etc then this function will also keep changing `post_views_count` value.

To prevent this function from doing that you can create another meta/custom field and set it's value to 1 if post is published atleast once in past. And check for this new field value before executing above code.

I will check other answer too, see if it's a better solution.

Comment: Robert, thank you for the detailed reply. You're really going above and beyond to help. I apologize, I was getting really frustrated by this problem. Here's the part that scares me: Adding a custom field. All posts follow the same structure and use the same post view count, so I'm afraid adding new custom fields will create some weirdness in the table. Do you share this concern? Is there a way around it?

Comment: You don't need to worry about custom fields because custom fields are kind of hidden/sleeping fields that contains some value or information. They do not do anything by themselves. They sit there in database and only return value/information if you call it. So no harm is done by creating a new field. Also, I was asking to create a new field if you change posts status very frequently. If you do not change status of published posts then the updated code I posted will work fine. Use that instead and let us know.

Comment: Just tested the code, something very interesting is happening. If I take a post that is pending review and publish it, it doesn't work. It shows up with 0 views. However, if I change that post back to draft, then republish it, the views jump to a value between 829 and 1013. Even more odd, if I just create a draft right now and publish it straight away, the code works immediately. Does that give you any ideas as to what might be happening?

Comment: I think some other function or plugin might have been overwriting it. Anyway I have made a edit in code. Use that and let me know. Now this function will also create custom field on pending review posts. It should work fine now.

Comment: Did it work as you want?

Comment: Hello, it looks like it's not working quite yet. I had an article pending review, I clicked Publish, and it published with 0 views. I was able to diagnose further oddities, maybe they'll give you an idea. When I open the post and publish it (post.php), it doesn't work. If I save it back as draft and republish it from post.php, it still doesn't work. But If I do it from the Posts page (edit.php), it works. Any ideas? This is very puzzling.

Comment: Clarification: In edit.php I do it in the Quick Edit menu, that's where it works.

Comment: The issue is your plugin, it fires way before. Try disabling and let us know.

Comment: I have several plugins, disabling them wouldn't be an option. A couple of thoughts: 1. I placed your code at the bottom of functions.php, would moving it up make any difference? 2. Could you please modify the code so that it sets the view count on any save, if views are zero? Basically, if views = 0, execute the code, no matter if it's being saved as draft or published. This would solve the problem I think!

Comment: I think the problem is postviews plugin. It's setting custom field value to 0. That plugin's code is overwriting this function there. Try disabling this plugin. Or you can modify plugin's code to set random value. Contact plugin developer for more info on this changes.

Comment: You're right, it must be the theme doing it. I wouldn't be able to contact the developer, however I feel we're very close. Would you be able to take a stab at the code that would do: if (views == 0) setvalue(); regardless of whether I'm publishing or saving as draft. That way it can just get that step out of the way ahead of time. Thanks! :)

Comment: I have a quick update if you'd like to read it. After using the code for several days, I know exactly what's happening: After publishing a post, if it has 0 views the code doesn't work, if it has one or more views, the code works! When I publish a post with 0 views, I just view it, then save as draft and republish, and since it has 1 view, it works! Does that give you any ideas on how to tweak it? Thank you!